# WebClient works, wget doesn't (when run under SYSTEM account)

Tags: powershell, webclient, wget

I'm using a powershell script to get information from a URL using basic authentication. This works well using all the common techniques: `wget`, `Invoke-WebRequest` and `System.Net.WebClient`.

When that same script is running using Task Scheduler as SYSTEM account, only `System.Net.WebClient` works.

Any suggestions as to why that is the case?

Comment: By `wget`, do you mean the executable or the alias? If latter is the case, I suggest you to remove that example, because it equals to IWR

Comment: Thanks Clijisters, I didn't realise that

Answer (score 1):

Probably because SYSTEM not has the same path and no initialized Powershell Profile.

For [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-5.1) you need the Module [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/?view=powershell-5.1), so either use [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-5.1) or [`#requires`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires?view=powershell-5.1) in the script.

For `wget` it might be the path, try using full paths to file? Either that or set working directory in scheduled task.